# Hardcoded data refreshing itself on every web api request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, arraylist, postman

I have been giving hours on understanding the hard-coded Model List concept in MVC.
Below are my codes that have a problem with the `List<employee> employees` variable.

```
using sampleProject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sampleProject.Services
{
    public class SampleData : ISampleData
    {
        private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee()
            {
                id=1,
                Name="Shubham",
                Code=1001,
                Email="a@a.com"
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                id=2,
                Name="Shubham2",
                Code=1002,
                Email = "a2@a.com"
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                id=3,
                Name="Shubham3",
                Code=1003,
                Email="a3@a.com"
            }

        };
        public Employee CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            employee.id = employees.Count() + 1;
            employees.Add(employee);
            return employee;
        }

        public String DeleteEmployee(int id)
        {
            employees.Remove(GetEmployee(id));
            return "Employee record with id : " + id.ToString() + " deleted";
        }

        public Employee EditEmployee(int id, Employee employee)
        {
            var existingEmployee = GetEmployee(id);
            existingEmployee.Name = employee.Name;
            existingEmployee.Code = employee.Code;
            existingEmployee.Email = employee.Email;
            return existingEmployee;
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int? Id)
        {
            return (employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == Id));
        }

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return employees;
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is that I can add, update, delete but when checking GetEmployees() gives me just the three records hardcoded by me.
please, Help.

Comment: I notice that you use the `asp.net-web-api` tag, thus implying that something may be done via a http request (api)? Then your `SampleData` will only live for the scope where it is created. For eg. within an request. Can you share your code where you use `SampleData` so that we can help you further?

Answer (score 1):

You likely use the SampleData as a scoped service. So each time a request comes through a new instance of SampleData is created (and thus it recreates the Employees list). What you need in a real application is a data storage. Save to disk, database or whatever. I'm guessing this is just for learning, so I'll provide you a simple solution.
You should make the Employees list static. This way the same list is used for every instance of SampleData:

```
private static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
{
        new Employee()
        {
            id=1,
            Name="Shubham",
            Code=1001,
            Email="a@a.com"
        },
        new Employee()
        {
            id=2,
            Name="Shubham2",
            Code=1002,
            Email = "a2@a.com"
        },
        new Employee()
        {
            id=3,
            Name="Shubham3",
            Code=1003,
            Email="a3@a.com"
        }

    };
```

Another option would be to make this class a singleton, but then I'd need to see more of your code.